# MCRYPT_BLOWFISH Error in magento server migration

Tags: magento2, migration, mcrypt

I'm getting this error followed in the Magento exception.log. I made a migration to a new server running PHP7 + and the mcrypt module is working.

```
[2018-04-14 13:54:44] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\jcell\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 397 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\jcell\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Encryption\\Encryptor.php on line 397 at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\jcell\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
[2018-04-14 13:54:46] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\jcell\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 397 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\jcell\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Encryption\\Encryptor.php on line 397 at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\jcell\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

mcrypt package for php is missing.
Try to install it

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and enable extension mcrypt.so